# bourne shell whitespace intricacies

Tags: shell, whitespace

```
$ freebsd-version 
10.3-RELEASE-p17
$

portinstall() {
    port="$1"; shift
    env="$@"

    #1
    env "$@" printenv | grep -E '^WITH(OUT)?='
    #2
    env "$env" printenv | grep -E '^WITH(OUT)?='
    #3
    env "$*" printenv | grep -E '^WITH(OUT)?='
    #4
    env $@ printenv | grep -E '^WITH(OUT)?='
    #5
    env $* printenv | grep -E '^WITH(OUT)?='

}


portinstall foo/bar WITH='baz xyzzy' WITHOUT='quux'
```

Only #1 works, its output:

```
 WITHOUT=quux
 WITH=baz xyzzy
```

With #2,#3 (WITH is just one variable "baz xyzzy WITHOUT=quux"):

```
  WITH=baz xyzzy WITHOUT=quux
```

With #4,#5

```
 env: xyzzy: No such file or directory
```

My main question is why #1 works but the seemingly equivalent #2 doesn't?

Comment: The problem with `env $@ printenv` is lacking double quotes, `env` runs with multiple arguments (more than one) which it doesn't like, hence the error, Double-quoting should fix it!

Comment: @Inian, yup, #4-5 are pretty self explanatory, I listed them for completeness' sake. My confusion is with #1-2.

Answer (score 2):

Using `"$@"` is most often correct, but maybe this analysis will help you understand why.

Your code is approximately:

```
env="$@"

#1
env "$@" printenv | grep -E '^WITH(OUT)?='
#2
env "$env" printenv | grep -E '^WITH(OUT)?='
#3
env "$*" printenv | grep -E '^WITH(OUT)?='
#4
env $@ printenv | grep -E '^WITH(OUT)?='
#5
env $* printenv | grep -E '^WITH(OUT)?='
```

and you're invoking the script with arguments `WITH='baz xyzzy' WITHOUT='quux'`.  Yes, you've got a function and a spare argument as `$1` adding to the complexity, but they're mostly irrelevant; this is the core.

In general, `$*` maps to the words in the arguments separated by spaces; `$@` does the same.  When enclosed in double quotes, they behave differently: `"$@"` expands to the set of arguments preserving internal spaces, while `"$*"` maps to a single string with internal spaces preserved and a single space between arguments.

However, in the context of `env="$@"`, the assignment behaves like `env="$*"` — you end up with a single string in the variable.  To preserve the separate arguments, in Bash, you'd use an array:

```
env=("$@")
```

and you could print them using:

```
printf '%s\n' "${env[@]}"
```

However, that's off at a tangent.

With #1, you end with an invocation of `env` with two valid, space-preserving assignments, which `printenv` duly prints and `grep` filters, giving you the two variable values.  This is why `"$@"` is usually correct.

With #2 and #3, you end up with an invocation of `env` with a single string that starts `WITH=` (so it assigns to the variable `WITH`, and the remainder of the string is `baz xyzzy WITHOUT=quux`, which is why you see that as the output.  There's a single environment variable — WITH — but its value contains spaces and an assignment.

With #4 and #5, you've run:

```
env WITH=baz xyzzy WITHOUT=quux printenv
```

Since `xyzzy` is not an assignment, it is treated as a command to be invoked with arguments `WITHOUT=quux` and `printenv` (and with `WITH=baz` added to the environment), but you don't have a program called `xyzzy` on your PATH, so `env` gives you the error.  You could create a program `xyzzy` to show that's what's happening.

With the array `env`, you could run:

```
env "${env[@]}" printenv | …
```

and you'd get the same result as #1.

Comment: Good read: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and

Comment: Thank you very very much for a very detailed explanation!!